# Extjs 6 'c is not a constructor'

Tags: extjs6

My app is working fine during development and the file download is working great.

Now after building the app with -production this code sipped fails.
It tries to load some "/.js" file without an name ?!?

I have this in my view `requires : ['Ext.form.FormPanel'],`

The log messages are printed but the form submit fails with `c is not a constructir` :(

```
    onInvoiceDownloadButtonClicked : function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {

    console.log('button pressed');
    var fp = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        url : 'back/invoice/get/' + record.get('id'),
        standardSubmit : true,
        method : 'POST'
    });

    console.log(fp);
    fp.form.submit();

}
```

---

Yes there is a synchronous loading warning but with .js ? No filename hmm

[image]

Comment: The problem is going to be a missing requirement somewhere. I can't tell you exactly what is missing, but I can tell you how to find out. Use the Javascript console while browsing your app in the development build - if you see anything about Synchronously downloading a file, that's a missing requirement.

Comment: What was at the end? I have the same problem

Answer (score 11):

Build the Application with testing mode using the following command:

```
sencha app build testing
```

and check the browser for more detailed errors.

Answer (score 2):

That happens when a file that it needs is missing. It's a very generic message, check you have all the files needed via .Requires in your code.

It's caught me out before where I had the right files, but they weren't loading in the order they were being called.